# XML eBay Trading API - addItem with multiple shipping options

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I want to list some item on eBay via there Trading API, but their API is very complicated and I need some help.

I can list items on eBay via the API very well but I can't seem to figure out how to have more than one shipping option as I can do on the eBay `addItem` page

Here is the shipping setting I need to have on eBay via the API
http://i.cubeupload.com/F4oURU.png

and this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<AddItemsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">  
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>  
<AddItemRequestContainer>  
<MessageID>100</MessageID>  
<Item>  
<StartPrice currencyID=\"CAD\">223.96</StartPrice>  
<CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>  
<ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>  
<Country>CA</Country>  
<Currency>CAD</Currency>  
<Title>TEST</Title>  
<Description>DEscription</Description>  
<DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>  
<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>  
<ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>  
<PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>  
<PayPalEmailAddress>  [--  myPayPalEmail --]  </PayPalEmailAddress>  
<PictureDetails>  
<Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>  
http://www.jccayer.com/productphoto/2793-22-1_ep1.jpg  
</Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>  
<PictureURL>http://www.jccayer.com/productphoto/2793-22-1_ep1.jpg</PictureURL>  
</PictureDetails>  
<PostalCode>K0A1M0</PostalCode>  
<PrimaryCategory>  
<CategoryID>279</CategoryID>  
</PrimaryCategory>  
<Quantity>6</Quantity>  
<ReturnPolicy>  
<ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>  
<RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>  
<ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>  
<Description>Text description of return policy details</Description>  
<ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>  
</ReturnPolicy>  
<ShippingDetails>  
<ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>  
<ShippingServiceOptions>  
<ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardCanada</ShippingService>  
<ShippingServiceCost>21.50</ShippingServiceCost>  
<ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>5.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>  
<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>  
</ShippingServiceOptions>  
<InternationalShippingServiceOption>  
<ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardUnitedStates</ShippingService>  
<ShippingServiceCost>50.50</ShippingServiceCost>  
<ShippingServiceCost>10.00</ShippingServiceCost>  
<ShipToLocation></ShipToLocation>  
<ShippingServicePriority>2</ShippingServicePriority>  
</InternationalShippingServiceOption>  
</ShippingDetails>  
<Site>Canada</Site>  
</Item>  
</AddItemRequestContainer>  
<RequesterCredentials>  
<eBayAuthToken>[INSERT YOUR OWN AUTH TOKEN]</eBayAuthToken>  
</RequesterCredentials>  
</AddItemsRequest>
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can match those setting on that picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This walks you through the XML needed to specify shipping details for an item on eBay.

### Example Shipping Details

The shipping cost model used by the seller is the **Flat** model. The seller offers domestic shipping within Canada via **UPS Standard Canada** at a charge of **CAD($)15.99** for the first item and **$6.00** for each additional. The item can also be shipped internationally and two services are offered for this. The first international service only ships to the **United States** using **UPS Standard United States** and costs **$21.08** for the first item and **$8.00** for each additional. The second service costs **$69.32** for the first item and **$29.00** for each additional. **UPS Worldwide Expedited** is used and will ship to the following locations.

- N. and S. America
- Mexico
- Germany
- Europe
- France
- United Kingdom
- Japan
- Asia
- Taiwan
- Australia

### The XML

Shipping information is specified in the *ShippingDetails* element of your request. This is of the type *ShippingDetailsType* and a complete list of fields is available [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/ShippingDetailsType.html).

```
<ShippingDetails>
    <!-- Domestic and international shipping details will be added here -->
</ShippingDetails>
```

The first piece of information we can add to *ShippingDetails* is the shipping model that the seller is using which in this case is *Flat*.

```
<ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
```

There are many different values that could be entered as the *ShippingType* and a complete list can be found [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/ShippingTypeCodeType.html).

We can now move onto the domestic shipping part of the request. You can specify up to a maximum of 4 domestic shipping services. Each service is a *ShippingServiceOptions* element and is of the type *ShippingServiceOptionsType*. A complete list of fields is available [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/ShippingServiceOptionsType.html).

```
<ShippingServiceOptions>
    <!-- Shipping costs and options related to a 
         domestic shipping service will be added here -->
</ShippingServiceOptions>
```

To control the order in which the domestic shipping services will appear in the View Item and Checkout page the seller can specify a priority. A service with a priority of 1 will appear at the top and a service with value of 4 will appear at the bottom. Note that in this example there is only one domestic shipping service so the priority is optional but it does no harm to include it.

```
<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
```

Specifying the cost of the shipping service is done with the *ShippingServiceCost* element. Since this seller is also charging for additional items the *ShippingServiceAdditionalCost* element needs to be specified as well.

```
<ShippingServiceCost>15.99</ShippingServiceCost>
<ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>6.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
```

Indicating that *UPS Standard Canada* will be used is done through the *ShippingService* element.

```
<ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardCanada</ShippingService>
```

Note that you do not actually specify *UPS Standard Canada* but instead use the value *CA_UPSStandardCanada*. Obtaining the correct value to use is outside the scope of this example but can be summarised as follows.

- Make a call to *GeteBayDetails* with *DetailName* set to *ShippingServiceDetails*.
- In the response iterate through each *ShippingServiceDetails* element and check for the existence of *ValidForSellingFlow*.
- If *ValidForSellingFlow* exists read in the value of *ShippingService*.
- More information can be found [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingServiceDetails).

We can now begin the first of the international shipping services. You can specify up to a maximum of 5 international shipping services. Each service is a *InternationalShippingServiceOption* element that is of the type *InternationalShippingServiceOptionsType*. A complete list of fields is available [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/InternationalShippingServiceOptionsType.html).

```
<InternationalShippingServiceOption>
    <!-- Shipping costs and options related to an 
         international shipping service will be added here -->
</InternationalShippingServiceOption>
```

Again the seller can specify a priority for each shipping service and for this we will enter a value of 1. Note that priorities are only compared between shipping services of the same type. This means that even though we have set a priority of 1 for both a domestic and international shipping service they will not be compared to each other when determining the order that they will appear.

```
<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
```

We can now add the costs for using this service.

```
<ShippingServiceCost>21.08</ShippingServiceCost>
<ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>8.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
```

*UPS Standard United States* is also added. Notice again that we don't actually specify *UPS Standard United States* but instead use a value that was retrieved when calling *GeteBayDetails*.

```
<ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardUnitedStates</ShippingService>
```

The seller has specified that this international shipping service will only ship to the United States. Indicating which location or region that the seller will ship to is done via the *ShipToLocation* element.

```
<ShipToLocation>US</ShipToLocation>
```

Once again we don't actually specify *United States* but instead use the value *US*. Obtaining the correct value to use is also outside the scope of this example but can be summarised as follows.

- Make a call to *GeteBayDetails* with *DetailName* set to *ShippingLocationDetails*.
- In the response iterate through each *ShippingLocationDetails* element and read in the value of *ShippingLocation*.
- More information can be found [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html#Response.ShippingLocationDetails).

Building the second international shipping service follows the same steps as the first. Notice that we set a priority of 2 as the seller wants it to appear below the first international shipping service. In addition several *ShipToLocation* elements have been specified to indicate the many regions that the seller will ship to with this service.

```
<InternationalShippingServiceOption>
    <ShippingServicePriority>2</ShippingServicePriority>
    <ShippingServiceCost>69.32</ShippingServiceCost>
    <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>29.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
    <ShippingService>CA_UPSWorldWideExpedited</ShippingService>
    <ShipToLocation>Americas</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>TW</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>Asia</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>AU</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>MX</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>DE</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>FR</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>Europe</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>GB</ShipToLocation>
    <ShipToLocation>JP</ShipToLocation>
</InternationalShippingServiceOption>
```

Putting together all the pieces results in the following XML.

```
<ShippingDetails>
    <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
    <ShippingServiceOptions>
        <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
        <ShippingServiceCost>15.99</ShippingServiceCost>
        <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>6.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
        <ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardCanada</ShippingService>
    </ShippingServiceOptions>
    <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
        <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
        <ShippingServiceCost>21.08</ShippingServiceCost>
        <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>8.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
        <ShippingService>CA_UPSStandardUnitedStates</ShippingService>
        <ShipToLocation>US</ShipToLocation>
    </InternationalShippingServiceOption>        
    <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
        <ShippingServicePriority>2</ShippingServicePriority>
        <ShippingServiceCost>69.32</ShippingServiceCost>
        <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>29.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
        <ShippingService>CA_UPSWorldWideExpedited</ShippingService>
        <ShipToLocation>Americas</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>TW</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>Asia</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>AU</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>MX</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>DE</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>FR</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>Europe</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>GB</ShipToLocation>
        <ShipToLocation>JP</ShipToLocation>
    </InternationalShippingServiceOption>
</ShippingDetails>
```

An example listing using these shipping details can be found [here](http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/110122064443). Note that this item may no longer exist.

Comment: Thanks Wow! it does work ! 

what i was missing is <ShipToLocation>